# circular queue inserting element problem when i try to insert 2nd element it is showing queue is full

Tags: c

In my circular queue when i enter 1st element it perfectly entered in the circular queue but when i enter 2nd element in the queue it show queue is full while the size of array is 5 even i debug it i found  after entering 1st element it is giving queue  is full statment
'''

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    # define SIZE 5
    int cqueue[SIZE];
    int front = -1;
    int rear = -1;
    void insert(int);
    void main()
    {
        int ch,item;
        while(1)
        {
            printf("\n select choice from given below operations of circular queue : ");
            printf("\n 1.insert element");
            printf("\n 2. delete element");
            printf("\n 3. display elements");
            printf("\n 4. exit");

            printf("\n enter choice : ");
            scanf("%d",&ch);

            switch(ch)
            {
                case 1 : printf("enter element : ");
                         scanf("%d",&item);
                         insert(item);
                         break;
                case 4 : exit(0);

                default: printf("\ninvalid choice! enter again\n");
            }
        }
    }

    void insert(int ele)
    {
        if(front=rear+1 || SIZE==rear+1)
        {
            printf("\n circular queue is full ");
        }
        else if((rear==-1)&&(front==-1))
        {
            front=rear=0;
            cqueue[rear]=ele;
        }
        else if(rear==SIZE-1)
        {
            rear=0;
            cqueue[rear]=ele;
        }
        else
        {
            rear++;
            cqueue[rear]=ele;
        }
    }
```

'''

Comment: `if (front = rear + 1 || ...)`: The assignment `=` should be a comparison for equality, `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *insert* function you have
`if(front=rear+1 || SIZE==rear+1)`. Change it to `if(front == rear + 1 ...`. So you are basically assigning `rear + 1` to `front` variable every time `insert` is called.